# pandas given two columns are same, find similar elements in rows to make new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my dataframe looks,

```
df = 
     query    subject     HPSame
0    cat      dog         HPS_1
1    cat      horse       HPS_2
2    king     queen       HPS_3
3    queen    people      HPS_4
4    CAR      VAN         HPS_5
5    dog      tiger       HPS_6
6    CAR      TRUCK       HPS_7
7    horse    deer        HPS_8
8    CAR      JEEP        HPS_9
9    TRUCK    LORRY       HPS_10
10   VAN      TRAIN       HPS_11
11   people   children    HPS_12
```

In the df, query is similar to subject, i:e, cat is similar to dog and hence label HPS_1. Also, cat is similar to horse, dog is similar to tiger, therefore, should have same match lable, HPS_1. I am looking to find similar elements like if a = b = c = d and give them same lable in new column. I have tried to simplify my question. The subject and query essentially consists of alphanumeric elements, WP_020314852.1 = WP_004217899.1 = WP_150395973.1 signifying same kind. The results expected is as follows.

```
df = 

     query    subject     HPSame   match
0    cat      dog         HPS_1    HPS_1
1    cat      horse       HPS_2    HPS_1
2    king     queen       HPS_3    HPS_3
3    queen    people      HPS_4    HPS_3
4    CAR      VAN         HPS_5    HPS_5
5    dog      tiger       HPS_6    HPS_1
6    CAR      TRUCK       HPS_7    HPS_5
7    horse    deer        HPS_8    HPS_1
8    CAR      JEEP        HPS_9    HPS_5
9    TRUCK    LORRY       HPS_10   HPS_5
10   VAN      TRAIN       HPS_11   HPS_5
11   people   children    HPS_12   HPS_3
```

I tried,

```
df['query_s'] = df['query'].shift(-1)
df['HPSame_s'] = df['HPSame'].shift(-1)
condition = [(df['query'] == df['query_s'])]
ifTrue = df['HPSame']
ifFalse = df['HPSame_s']
df['match'] = np.where(condition, ifTrue, ifFalse)
```

This throws me ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: I might be slow, but I understood nothing of 'cat is similar to dog and hence label HPS_1. Also, cat is similar to horse, dog is similar to tiger, therefore, should have same match lable, HPS_1.' How do you define similar ? How is the column 'match' calculated ?

Comment: Lets say, cat is a protein whose ID is WP_120314582.1 and dog is another protein with ID WP_13242761.5. Both the proteins are 100% similar, so they should get the same name although they have different IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this using [Networkx library](https://networkx.github.io/) with [graph theory connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)):

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

# Copy your input dataframe from question
df = pd.read_clipboard()

# Create a graph network
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'query', 'subject')

# Use connected_components method to find groups
grps = dict(enumerate(nx.connected_components(G)))

# Match back to dataframe
df['match'] = [k for i in df['query'] for k, v in grps.items() if i in v]
df['match'] = df.groupby('match')['HPSame'].transform('first')

print(df)
```

Output:

```
     query   subject  HPSame  match
0      cat       dog   HPS_1  HPS_1
1      cat     horse   HPS_2  HPS_1
2     king     queen   HPS_3  HPS_3
3    queen    people   HPS_4  HPS_3
4      CAR       VAN   HPS_5  HPS_5
5      dog     tiger   HPS_6  HPS_1
6      CAR     TRUCK   HPS_7  HPS_5
7    horse      deer   HPS_8  HPS_1
8      CAR      JEEP   HPS_9  HPS_5
9    TRUCK     LORRY  HPS_10  HPS_5
10     VAN     TRAIN  HPS_11  HPS_5
11  people  children  HPS_12  HPS_3
```

Image of the graph network from the dataframe:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))
nx.draw_networkx(G, node_color='y')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Scott for your time. Much appreciated!